# Semantic Text similarity NLP

Tags: nlp, semantic-similarity

I'm new to AIML. Right now I'm working with a requirement where I need to see if two sentences are similar semantically. I'm searching for an API which compares given sentance with another array of sentences and provide us with matching one from passed array of sentances. Just want to know if there is any proven algo/API implementation published now.

Please let me through this folks. Thanks in advance.